# Question about multiplicity of zeros of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm being asked to find the multiplicities of the zeros of $f(z)=\cosh^3z-1$. I know how to compute the roots one by one. I'd get $2n\pi i$, and 2 other roots in terms of $\cosh^{-1}$ (namely, $\cosh^{-1}(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i)$ and $\cosh^{-1}(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i)$). It gets really messy when I simplify $\cosh^{-1}$ into $\ln$. But I do know the multiplicity of $2n\pi i$ (which is 2). My question is: is there a way I could argue that all roots must have the same multiplicity, so that I wouldn't have to calculate the other two roots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't argue that all zeros of $f$ have the same multiplicity - they haven't.

But the generic case is that a zero of a holomorphic function has multiplicity $1$, and thus it is a promising strategy to check whether $f'(\zeta) \neq 0$ for a zero $\zeta$ of $f$ with $\zeta \notin 2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$.

Since $f'(z) = 3 (\cosh^2 z)\sinh z$, a zero $\zeta$ is a multiple zero of $f$ if and only if $\sinh \zeta = 0$. For a zero $\zeta\notin 2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$ of $f$, we have

$$\cosh \zeta = \exp \biggl(\pm \frac{2\pi i}{3}\biggr),$$

and therefore

$$\sinh^2 \zeta = \cosh^2 \zeta - 1 = \exp \biggl( \mp \frac{2\pi i}{3}\biggr) - 1 = \frac{-3\mp i \sqrt{3}}{2}\neq 0.$$

Thus all the zeros of $f$ except for $2n\pi i,\, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, are simple.

Comment: Woah. I understand. Thank you.